# phpMyAdmin (MAMP): Error while working with template cache: Unable to write in the cache directory

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

First post!  I am working on a client site, trying to get their website going on a local Apache server on my Mac using MAMP.  Am jumping thru hoops and this one has me stumped.  I've imported the site, created the database and am trying to connect to it thru phpAdmin.  I can get into the initial DB structure screen just fine, but when i click on the desired database, i get the following error:

"Error in processing request. Error code 500. Error text: Internal Server error (rejected). It seems the connection to your server has been lost.  Please check your network and server statistics".

I also get an error on the lower part of the screen:
"Error while working with template cache: Unable to write in the cache directory (/Applications/MAMP/tmp/phpMyAdmin/twig/3f)."

I checked the apache_error.log and mysql_error_log.err and they are both clean.  However, the php_error.log shows the issues:
"[16-Jul-2021 07:58:22 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to write in the cache directory (/Applications/MAMP/tmp/phpMyAdmin/twig/3f).' in /Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/vendor/twig/twig/src/Cache/FilesystemCache.php:61"

(and there's a stack trace that i can paste in if necessary....)

I've done some fairly extensive research and two things are suggested.

(1) the most common theory is that it is a permissions issue.  I've checked and given read/write privs to the world thru the whole chain of directories in the path listed above (/Applications/MAMP/tmp/phpMyAdmin/twig/*).  This does not solve the problem.

(2) it is recommended to download a more recent version of phpMyAdmin (just upgrade to the latest and greatest and all will be well!).  I also did this, followed the instructions and got the error saying that i needed to be on php version 7.1.3 or later.  As near as i can tell, there is no other option between my version (4.9.7) and the next (and current one) 5.1.1.  So that didn't work for me either.

I'm currently at php version 5.6.40 on this client site and upgrading is a no-go for me  (at least right now).

My environment is:
MAMP 6.3
PHP 5.6.40
MySql 5.7
phpMyAdmin version: 4.9.7 (the upgrade that i attempted above was to version 5.1).

I've been unable to find any other options.  Can anyone help me out?  I'm relatively new to PHP, but a pretty experienced software developer overall.

Comment: To see the actual error message, check your servers error log. You can also change how PHP displays errors and tell it to show all errors directly on the screen (this is not something you want in production though, since it can show sensitive data, but during development, you should). Here's how to show all errors and warnings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display (this works with the PHP 5.6 version in question as well)

Comment: Thanks for the response, it would have been helpful but i harassed my client into upgrading to a more recent version of PHP which solved the problem.  So, i dodged it entirely.

Comment: Not a bad decision to upgrade if you'd ask me.